# emulator-arm.exe no longer working

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

This is the message I receive always (100%) if I try to start the emulator with an existing  snapshot. The system is Windows 7 32bit, ADT14 and SDK14.

I need to start every emulator session with "wiped user data". Whenever I try to reload the emulator with a snapshot Windows prints this message (in German: emulator-arm.exe funktioniert nicht mehr) and the only option available is to close the application (emulator-arm.exe).

I can reproduce that at will. Even with fresh installs of Eclipse (Helios and Indigo), SDK, ADT. I could see that with all versions in the last year. I can reproduce that on three different machines in my house (all Windows 7 32bit) at will. There's not much software on my machines. On one machine is the Android Development environment only. All three computers are no gaming machines and don't have much power. I mean, just to use the Eclipse editor, it must be enough.

All applications (Eclipse, etc.) are not configured to special needs. I always use the Android development as is out of the box.

Any help is highly appreciated. It's not funny to always go for lunch or coffee just to switch from one emulator to the next one - lasts for approx. 10 minutes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I suggest not to use `Snapshot` features. Just having a normal reboot is totally fine, it doesn't take much time, just one or two minutes.

The `Snapshot` thing really troubled me in the past, and resulted in a newly-fresh installation of SDK. Don't know why it is exactly but it is better not to use `Snapshot`, first, it doesn't speed up your emulator speed; second, it is a emulator stuff, not on a real device.

Correct me if I'm wrong or mistaken something!

Comment: One or two minutes? That would be cool. I'm waiting ages for the emulator to start. I started it at 6:39. Now it's 6:48 and the only thing I see is the Android text on the black frame. There's only Eclipse running and my Chrome browser. This is a usual 2 year old Core2Duo notebook. Can't believe that ... Seems that Snapshots are broken. I will accept your answer because I will not try to use them any longer.

Comment: I'm having my old 5 year-old netbook Core2Duo, and running at most 5 emulators at a time, no `Snapshot`, all boots are done in at most 3 minutes, usually 90 sec :). Also a little note, after creating the AVD, if it failed to boot, just delete, make a new one; well, the first boot always takes the longest time, mine is around 7 min.

Comment: What? 5 emulators? Eclipse and one emulator eat up over 1 GB RAM here - and I don't have an SD card declared to the emulators. With 256 MB SD-card it takes an hour to start one emulator. How much RAM to you have in your Netbook?

Comment: only 3GB, one emulator consumes only 200-250MB, Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

Launch your AVD Device via the AVD Manager, ensure not to wipe user data or use launch from snapshot.

If your application is not deployed to AVD Device:

Right click your eclipse project select run as => run configuration. Ensure under the target tab deployment mode is set to manual. Click Run, from here you can select the current running AVD you started earlier.

To redeploy your application to AVD Device

Leave the AVD Device up and running, use the Application Manager on the AVD Device to uninstall the app from the AVD Device. Next, right click your eclipse project select run as => run configuration. Ensure under the target tab deployment mode is set to manual. Click Run, from here you can select the current running AVD you started earlier.